# How to read data from Unity3D's prefab file?

Tags: c#, file, unity-game-engine, stream, binary

So, I am trying to create an test application for online Unity game but to do what I need it to do, I must read datas from a hex offset located in a .prefab file.
And then, i will load prefabs on server-side from data. For an anti-collider hack from client-side.

I must read datas like unityVer, localScale, localPosition, localSize, collider size... etc.

Edit: I must make it on a simple console application, not in Unity.

My not working code :

```
try {
            string[] prefabFiles = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "data\\prefabs\\"));
            foreach (var prefab in prefabFiles) {
                if (prefab != null && prefab.Split('.')[1] == "prefab") {
                    try {
                        using (var reader = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(prefab, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))) {
                            FileInfo info = new FileInfo(prefab);
                            Console.WriteLine("Analyzing File : " + info.Name);

                            reader.BaseStream.Position = 0xA;

                            //string unityVer = reader...

                            //float localPositionX = reader...
                            //float localPositionY = reader...
                            //float localPositionZ = reader...

                            //float localScaleX = reader...
                            //float localScaleY = reader...
                            //float localScaleZ = reader...

                            //float colliderRadius = reader...
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("File parse success.");
                    } catch { Console.WriteLine("Parse error in the data file."); }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e_Ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(e_Ex.ToString());
        }
```

My Prefab's Hex Tree:

[HEX TREE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjaVg.jpg)

I am new to reading and writing data located in a hex data location so any help would be awesome!

Comment: I am afraid that without document explaining prefab binary file structure you will not be able to do it, unless you are good cracker. Out of this world solution is to get unity3d source files and check c++ file repsonsible for parsing prefabs, or just asking unity to give you document for it. But I maight be wrong, maybe someone will help you.

Comment: having the similar intent, i want to generate C# code from a prefab, so i don't have to manually create a data member and bind manually each time there is a new prefab from designer.

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer would be to save assets as YAML text files instead of binary. That format is human readable, which makes it much easier to decode. Under *Project Settings* -> *Editor*, there's *Asset Serialization*, which should be set to *Force Text*. Of course all existing assets are going to be re-imported and existing builds will have to be re-deployed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying too hard or I misunderstood your point.

When you have a prefab that is referenced in your project, Unity will create an instance of it, it just won't show in the scene and is kept internally. Then when you use Instantiate with it, it will duplicate all info and data.

That means you can access info on prefab the same way you would access them on any game object:

```
public GameObject myPrefab;

void Start(){
    Debug.Log(myPrefab.transform.position);
    Collider col = myPrefab.GetComponent<Collider>();
    // Use Collider
}
```

Comment: Oh, i must read data on normal C# project. No in Unity, it's easy to read. But not need.Independent with unity. (: Thanks...